# SQL query parameterization

Tags: sql

Could someone give an answer to the following please?

```
Statement statement;

string sql;

sql = "SELECT gender FROM people WHERE gender = 'M' ";

results = statement.executeQuery(sql);
```

What kind of formatting do I have to do to represent 'M' in my string SQL query?

Notes: gender is either 'M' or 'F' and I want to return all rows that are of gender 'M'.

Comment: What do you mean. What is datatype of gender?

Comment: I'm having trouble working out what you mean... care to word this question a bit differently?

Comment: The SQL you posted is correct; what error do you get?

Comment: Aaron: I don't get an error except I don't have a DBMS running on my computer so have to do it blind.

Comment: @Aaron: If you state your input as a response then I can give you the credit!

Comment: You're just going to get a list of M's in that result (if any are in the table). Did you want a `SELECT *` to get all the columns in the row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'M'` is the correct way to specify a value for a `VARCHAR` column if you write the query manually.

But a better way is usually to use a prepared statement:

```
stmt = connect.prepareStatement("SELECT gender FROM people WHERE gender = ?");
stmt.setString( 1, "M" );
```

The advantage of this approach is that JDBC will automatically convert the parameter for you, escape it properly, etc.

For example, your code will become much more complex for people's names after you tried to add `D'Angelo` (common Italian name) to your database.

Comment: I wonder if you know the answer to some JDBC. To access gender column which is of char(1) do I have to use results.getString(...)? or is there a getter like getChar(..)

Comment: You will have to use `getString()`. JDBC doesn't make a difference between different column widths.